# woocommerce_wp_select save selected option and display in front end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, custom-fields

I face a problem regarding `woocommerce_wp_select` . I am adding new fields to the single product page.  First, I add the options by the following codes:

```
$title_110 = array(
    'id' => 'custom_text_field_title_110',
    'label' => __( 'Awards', 'rasa_store' ),
    'desc_tip' => true,
    'description' => __( 'Select an option.', 'ctwc' ),
    'options'     => array(
        ''        => __( 'Select Option', 'woocommerce' ),
        '0'       => __('This product does not win any awards', 'woocommerce' ),
        '1'       => __('This product win on award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '2'       => __('This product win 2 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '3'       => __('This product win 3 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '4'       => __('This product very famous.', 'woocommerce' )
    ),
    ); 

woocommerce_wp_select( $title_110 );
```

Than I save it.

```
$attribute_110 = wc_get_product( $post_id );
$title_top_110 = isset( $_POST['custom_text_field_title_110'] ) ? $_POST['custom_text_field_title_110'] : '';
$attribute_110->update_meta_data( 'custom_text_field_title_110', sanitize_text_field( $title_top_110 ) );
$attribute_110->save();
```

But in front page of single product page, while I use :

```
$attribute_11 = wc_get_product ( $post->ID );
$title_top_110 = $attribute_11->get_meta( 'custom_text_field_title_110' );
if( $title_top_110  ) {
printf(
'<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img class="img-fluid box-10-2" src="%s/img/award-icon.png">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 box-10">
<p class="card-text box-10-1">%s</p>
</div>
</div>
',
esc_html( get_bloginfo('template_directory')  ),
esc_html( $title_top_110 )
);
}
```

Instead of printing  `This product does not win any awards` I see `0`.
I am looking for finding a way to fix it. I test the following methods, and they do not work:

```
1. Replaced update_post_meta() by get_post_meta()
2. Replaced esc_html to esc_sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some different ways:

You need an additional custom function for your dropdown options this way:

```
function custom_field_options_title_110() {
    return array(
        ''        => __( 'Select Option', 'woocommerce' ),
        '0'       => __('This product does not win any awards', 'woocommerce' ),
        '1'       => __('This product win on award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '2'       => __('This product win 2 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '3'       => __('This product win 3 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
        '4'       => __('This product very famous.', 'woocommerce' )
    );
}
```

Then you will call that function everywhere is needed:

- In backend on your `woocommerce_wp_select()` code:

  ```
  woocommerce_wp_select( array(
      'id'          => 'custom_text_field_title_110',
      'label'       => __( 'Awards', 'rasa_store' ),
      'desc_tip'    => true,
      'description' => __( 'Select an option.', 'ctwc' ),
      'options'     => custom_field_options_title_110(), // <== Here we call our options function
  ) );
  ```
- And now **on frontend for single product page**:

  ```
  $attribute_11 = wc_get_product ( $post->ID );
  $title_top_110 = $attribute_11->get_meta( 'custom_text_field_title_110' );
  if( ! empty($title_top_110) ) {
      printf( '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><img class="img-fluid box-10-2" src="%s"></div>
          <div class="col-md-8 box-10"><p class="card-text box-10-1">%s</p></div></div>',
          esc_html( get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/img/award-icon.png'  ),
          esc_html( custom_field_options_title_110()[$title_top_110] ) // <== HERE we use it
      );
  }
  ```

It should work…

---

**Another alternative** is to have the same keys and values in your 'options' array like:

```
$options_title_110 = array( '' => __( 'Select Option', 'woocommerce' ) );

foreach ( array(
    __('This product does not win any awards', 'woocommerce' ),
    __('This product win on award.', 'woocommerce' ),
    __('This product win 2 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
    __('This product win 3 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
    __('This product very famous.', 'woocommerce' )
) as $label ) {
    $options_title_110[$label] = $label;
}

woocommerce_wp_select( array(
    'id'          => 'custom_text_field_title_110',
    'label'       => __( 'Awards', 'rasa_store' ),
    'desc_tip'    => true,
    'description' => __( 'Select an option.', 'ctwc' ),
    'options'     => $options_title_110,
) );
```

Then the custom field selected value will be saved on backend and displayed on front end.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the options as you where doing, so this part should work as intended

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_text_field_title_110' );
function woo_add_custom_text_field_title_110(){
    $title_110 = array(
        'id' => 'custom_text_field_title_110',
        'label' => __( 'Awards', 'rasa_store' ),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'Select an option.', 'ctwc' ),
        'options'     => array(
            ''        => __( 'Select Option', 'woocommerce' ),
            '0'       => __('This product does not win any awards', 'woocommerce' ),
            '1'       => __('This product win on award.', 'woocommerce' ),
            '2'       => __('This product win 2 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
            '3'       => __('This product win 3 award.', 'woocommerce' ),
            '4'       => __('This product very famous.', 'woocommerce' )
        ),
    ); 
    
    woocommerce_wp_select( $title_110 );
}
```

To save the fields

```
// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_text_field_title_110_save' );
function woo_add_custom_text_field_title_110_save( $post_id ){
  // Select
  $title_top_110  = $_POST['custom_text_field_title_110'];
  if( !empty( $title_top_110 ) )
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_text_field_title_110', esc_attr( $title_top_110 ) );
  else {
      update_post_meta( $post_id, 'custom_text_field_title_110',  '' );
  }
}
```

And to output the data on single product page (this code needs to be modified to output it inside the loop)

```
$title_top_110 = get_post_meta( 'custom_text_field_title_110', $post->ID, true );
if( $title_top_110  ) {
  printf(
  '<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <img class="img-fluid box-10-2" src="%1$s/img/award-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 box-10">
  <p class="card-text box-10-1">%2$s</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  ',
  esc_html( get_bloginfo('template_directory')  ),
  esc_html( $title_top_110 )
  );
}
```